# Javascript in HTML, struggling to make a for loop work for a button

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, innerhtml

I'm trying to practice using JavaScript in HTML, and am having some trouble.
The goal for me right now is to have a button that, when pressed, prints out a series of breaks and descending numbers down to 1 like a countdown. Once I've got the function implemented into the page, I'd work in a textbox that the user can use to have their own number that counts down to 1. Pretty simple, but I've hit a wall. I'm trying to do this using a .js library located in the same folder as the HTML file. Here's how my HTML looks:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- project10.html -->

<html>
    <head>
        Hello!
    </head>
    <body>
        <title>Testing Function</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <p id="demo" onclick="myFunction(5)">Click this text to show a countdown.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not the cleanest, I know. Here's the test.js located in the same folder:

```
function myFunction(b2){
    for (i=b2;i>0;i--){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `5<1` is never true

Comment: Try changing it to `i > 0`

Comment: Success. Thank you for that. However, when I click the text, it just removes the text, replacing it with nothing.

Comment: Right, because `innerHTML = 'thing'` replaces the value, it doesn't append it.  `.innerHTML += i +'<br>';` .... `+=` will append

Comment: I didn't even know += was a thing for .innerHTML... and trying it... it worked. Wow. Thanks a bunch mate. Hoping I'm this fluent in a couple years...

Comment: also set a timeout, your loop will run in less then a sec, you wont see any countdown.... Add `console.log(i)` inside loop to check it.

Comment: No need to say `type="javascript"`, that's what it already is under HTML5 rules (you only need `type` if it's _not_ javascript). Having said that, please don't use `onclick="..."`, keep your JS _in your js_ by getting your element and then using `element.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { ... })` (or using a modern arrow function). You're using a very old kind of JS here, so I suspect you're learning from an old tutorial. It's worth finding a modern one that teaches HTML5 with JS that it calls "ES6" (or ES2016...ES2020 depending on how modern it is).